# call to undefined method php error

Tags: php

I have a class called CHCID which has the two functions inside it:

```
public function UpdateDeliveryAddress($orderNumber, $deliveryaddress) {

    $sql = "UPDATE `CIDOrders`

    SET `DeliveryAddress` = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($deliveryaddress) . "'

    WHERE `CIDOrderNumber` = " . $orderNumber . ";";

    mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE_NAME, $this->conn);

    return mysql_query($sql, $this->conn);

}

public function UpdateInvoiceAddress($orderNumber, $invoiceAddress) {

    $sql = "UPDATE `CIDOrders`

    SET `InvoiceAddress` = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($invoiceaddress) . "'

    WHERE `CIDOrderNumber` = " . $orderNumber . ";";

    mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE_NAME, $this->conn);

    return mysql_query($sql, $this->conn);

}
```

I call this class in a page called createorder.php as follow:

```
// Add a new delivery address to the order

$cid->UpdateDeliveryAddress($_POST['orderNumber'], $_POST['deliveryaddress']);

// Add invoice address to the order

$cid->UpdateInvoiceAddress($_POST['orderNumber'], $_POST['invoiceaddress']);
```

I get the following error :

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method CHCID::UpdateDeliveryAddress()
```

Can anyone help.

Many thanks

Code initialising the class.

```
require_once $CID_INCLUDE_PATH . "/cid.php";

$cid = new CHCID();
```

Constructing class

```
class CHCID {



    var $conn;



    // Constructor, connect to the database

    public function __construct() {

        require_once "/var/www/reporting/settings.php";

        if(!$this->conn = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD)) die(mysql_error());

        if(!mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE_NAME, $this->conn)) die(mysql_error());

    }
```

Comment: Have you put `$cid = New CHCID();` before `$cid->UpdateDeliveryAddress()`? `$cid` isn't an object without being declared one.

Comment: yep at the top of the page  // And create a cid object

 require_once $CID_INCLUDE_PATH . "/cid.php";

 $cid = new CHCID();

Comment: Are you instantiating an object of class `CHCID`? I assume that's what `$cid` is, but it would be nice to see the instantiation.

Comment: Could you show us how you're declaring your CHCID class and how are you instantiating the $cid object?

Comment: // And create a cid object

 require_once $CID_INCLUDE_PATH . "/cid.php";

 $cid = new CHCID();

Comment: @user969733 can you show how you create the class (including with the `class CHCID {...}`

Comment: class CHCID {

  

  var $conn;

  

  // Constructor, connect to the database

  public function __construct() {

   require_once "/var/www/reporting/settings.php";

   if(!$this->conn = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD)) die(mysql_error());

   if(!mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE_NAME, $this->conn)) die(mysql_error());

  }

Comment: Please don't post code in comments as it is impossible to read. Revise your question to include the requested code.

Comment: @user969733 put that in your question... not in the comments....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If those function were really in your class, this would never happen.

Check `$CID_INCLUDE_PATH`, you're probably loading a different file, maybe an older version of the class. Also enable warnings, notices...

Comment: @user969733: accept the answer so others know the problem is resolved.